# 'F12' Tool of IE11 did not recognize conditional stylesheets

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools, conditional-comments

I have a site which should compatible with multiple browsers, like IE7 & IE8 & others.
I choose to use conditional stylesheet to deal with different version of IEs.

Like this, only include ie7.css if current browser is ie7.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I use IETester to test the performance of my site and make change for specific version of ie.

Everything look fine and consistent in IETester.

But, when I use the 'F12' tool of IE11 and change the version of IE, the appearance of my site scared me, element's position are disordered and looks ugly.

It seems that my conditional stylesheets(like ie7.css) do not loaded cause I do not see the ie7 styles displayed in the DOM Explorer.

Is this a IE11 bug ? or something else?

anybody knows?

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in F12 where conditional comments aren't respected when using F12 to set the document mode. This bug was fixed in the April update to IE11. If you run Windows update to get the latest patch you shouldn't see this issue any more.
http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806767/conditional-comments-do-not-work-when-emulating-document-modes-via-f12-developer-tools